# how nginx + uwsgi handle multiply connections?

Tags: nginx, networking, network-programming, webserver, uwsgi

I have such `uwsgi` config in `nginx`:

```
        worker_connections 768;
        ...
        #later in config
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";
        uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/site.sock;
```

and run `uwsgi` like this:

```
uwsgi --umask 117 --need-plugins python3 -s /run/uwsgi/site.sock -w index:app
```

How exactly multiply connections handling by this bundle (`nginx` and `uwsgi`)?

I mean, let's say `nginx` recieve 100 connections in the same time,
and it works on Linux with one CPU,
each connection is `http` `GET` request.

Then `nginx` handle it by itself with async I/O until get full package of `GET` request, right?

Then `nginx` order that requests and one by one in consecutive order pass them to `uwsgi` via unix socket?

Then how `uwsgi` handle that, it can run as many process/threads as it wants,
but it should return answer to `nginx` via unix socket in the same order as recieve requests?

If the same, then it means that additional processes/threads ran by `uwsgi` are senseless, if not the same order then how `nginx` understand where answer to which request?